# In a ring R, if there exists a in R s.t. ab=0 for any b in R, then a must be 0. Is this statement true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a general ring $R$, if there exists $a$ in $R$ s.t. $ab=0$ for any $b$ in $R$, then $a$ must be $0$. Is this statement true?

Comment: Do your rings have identity?

Comment: Not necessarily. If it does, then the problem becomes trivial: taking b=1 suffices

Comment: The question is unclear: when you say "for any" do you mean "for all" or "for at least one"?  Separately: You have stated the broader context of the question in a comment below an answer. In general, it's better to include context in the original question. Questions that are simply a statement of a problem, such as this one, are often put on hold for improvement.

Comment: If the ring doesn't have a unit, it's not true: let $A$ be any abelian group and define $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your definition of a ring.  If $R$ is a ring with unity, then yes: we may simply select $b = 1_R$, and the result follows.  If not, we can take the subring $\{0,2\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4$, and note that $2$ is such an element.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am working with the following problem: Let S be an R-algebra finitely generated as an R-module. Now I want to show that any s in S satisfies an integral equation. By Cayley-Hamilton Theorem there is a polynomial p(x) in R[x] such that p(s)*t=0 for any t in S. But what I need is that p(s)=0. I don't know how to make the last step. Thanks!

Comment: Is this from a textbook?  Check the definition of a ring.  This isn't from Atiya MacDonald by any chance, is it?

Comment: It's from a theorem in Eisenbud's _Commutative Algebra_, and the ring R is only assumed to be commutative

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  That's strange, because in the context of algebras we usually take rings to be unital.  Not sure where to go from there if it isn't.

Comment: Oh, I just looked up on Wikipedia and found out that rings are usually taken to be unital. I skipped the first chapters of that book and perhaps I missed some of the assumptions in the book. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @user160307 Eisenbud will definitely be viewing all of his rings as having $1$.